# Check a program existence in PATH

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, file-exists

I'm running batch scripts (usually from Visual Studio) and want to check that some program available through the `PATH` and if not - then show a message. Simple file checking like

```
if exist mingw32-make (echo "exists") else (echo "not exists")
```

not working - shell always thinking that app is not exists (maybe because it not looking into `PATH`).
How to do this right and clean?

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a free script writing service. Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried, describe what it does, and describe what it should do. Include any error messages that the code produces. See also `WHERE /?`.

Comment: So I can't ask about `cmd` batching language (I saw same questions about bash) or you mean something another?

Comment: The cmd.exe shell will try to resolve an executable through the PATH when it runs. The IF EXIST does not resolve through the PATH. Did you investigate `WHERE /?`?

Comment: @TrolltheLegacy, of course you can ask an on-topic question about `cmd` (see [ask])...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` checks, if the given file exists within the path (or on the current working folder `%cd%`) and gives either the full path(s) or an error message. Both you don't need - just the errorlevel:

```
where mingw32-make >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (echo "not exists") else (echo "exists")
```

or as a shortcut:

```
where /q mingw32-make && echo found || echo not found
```